# Using a ConcurrentQueue for monitoring a chain of tasks

Tags: c#, task

I've been working on a system which deals with a large queue of inserts to a SQL database. The data for these inserts is fetched from a series of API making the overall operation a little time consuming and a bit heavy due to complex deserialization. In order to make the overall process more efficient, I have come up with this idea of encapsulating data processing and the insert operation for each API call into a single Task and pushing each Task into a `ConcurrentQueue` while monitoring them for either completion or failure later. To do so, I have developed a wrapper around the `Task` type with an assignable Id which belongs to its corresponding data. I have implemented this monitoring as follows:

```
while(processes.TryDequeue(out TaskInfo taskInfo))
{
    if (!taskInfo.Task.IsCompleted) {
        processes.Enqueue(taskInfo);
        continue;
    }
    if (taskInfo.Task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed.", taskInfo.ReferenceId);
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Failed With {1}.", taskInfo.ReferenceId, trackableTask.Task.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

As you see, I do not `await` the task and instead I check for its `Completed` status and if it is not yet completed I `Enqueue` the task back. The reason why I did that I because I believed if I do so, I can skip waiting for a long running task by moving it to the end of the collection so I that I can move to the next task and do the monitoring process a bit faster.

I would like to know if what I have done is a bad approach particularly in comparison with the `WhenAll` method built into the task type. I'm also unsure if what I did is a proper usage of the `ConcurrentQueue` type.

Comment: Is your queue being accessed from multiple threads? It doesn't appear so. If not, you can (should) use a plain old `Queue<T>`; otherwise the concurrent queue is acquiring unnecessary locks every time you access it. `TryDequeue` turns into `Dequeue` (now within the loop) and the while loop tests for `Count>0`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Good point! Thanks.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: But I can still use `tryDequeue`, do you think there would be anything wrong with using that?

Comment: Do you know what TryDequeue does? It's meant for a scenario when you have (for example) 1 item in your queue but two threads try and Dequeue at the exact same time. One will get the item (and return true) the other will get nothing (and return false). You're not using your queue in a multithreaded scenario so what benefit does TryDequeue give you? Nothing. Instead it gives you the overhead of unnecessary locking

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Does it also apply to the `TryDequeue` available in the `Queue` type? Asking that because `Queue` is not meant for a mult-threaded scenario as you said. Just wanna make sure.

Comment: From what I can tell `Queue<T>` may have had a `TryDequeue` method added as part of dotnetcore, yet left *undocumented* (seems to be the case based on some github issues and the fact it's not documented on msdn). The point behind adding that Api was because `Dequeue` throws if the count is 0. So Instead of `while(queue.Count >0) { var item = queue.Dequeue();}` you could now write `while (queue.TryDequeue(out var item) {..} `. So... If `TryDequeue` is available to you as a member of the `Queue<T>` class, then yes it's perfectly OK to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working that queue with only a single thread, you can use a regular queue.
Concurrent Queue is helpfull when you try acessing the queue with multiple threads. E.G the threads that are inside of your queue :)

While reading your code i wonder whether you have heard of TPL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

or PLINQ:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq

these may help you out with your task(s) ;)